# Inner joining on multiple tables but only selecting one

Tags: sql, inner-join

I am joining two different tables to my original table, but I want to only inner join on one of the two (depending on if it is the one that contains a matching key). Basically, it will be impossible for both table that are being joined to have the same record as the original. I need at most one.

Something like...

```
SELECT
t.Id,
t.column1,
t.column2,
a.column3 as ‘Column 3’,
b.column4 as ‘Column x’,
s.column5,
t.column6
FROM “Table1” t
INNER JOIN “Table2” a on a.Id = t.Id
INNER JOIN “Table3” b on b.Id = t.Id
```

Only one of 2 or 3 should be joined on if the Id exists in that specific table.

Comment: So what is your specific question?

Comment: You could union them together in a subquery and select on that. But... you will probably lose any indexing gains. What is the problem with doing it the way you are doing it now. You could use `COALESCE()` in your SELECT clause to combine fields that are common between `a` and `b`. Ultimately though, I'm not sure what your question/problem is.

Comment: if you add sample data and expected output data , it will be easier to answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `left join`:

```
SELECT t.*,
       a.column3 as Column3,
       b.column4 as Columnx
FROM Table1 t LEFT JOIN 
     Table2 a 
     ON a.Id = t.Id LEFT JOIN
     Table3 b 
     ON b.Id = t.Id;
```

This is often used with `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT t.*, coalesce(a.col1, b.col1) as col1
FROM Table1 t LEFT JOIN 
     Table2 a 
     ON a.Id = t.Id LEFT JOIN
     Table3 b 
     ON b.Id = t.Id;
```